# Print (2) columns from powershell array

Tags: powershell

I created this array with:

```
$arecords = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "mydomain.local" -RRType "A"
```

If I do `$arecords.HostName` I get a list of the hostnames. If I do `$arecords.RecordData` I get a list of the IP's. How can print both columns AWK style? Like `$arecords.Hostname.RecordData`?

Comment: So close! The only problem with that is strangely RecordData is printing "DnsServerResourceRecordA" instead of the value (the IP):

HostName  RecordData
dc1-adc2    DnsServerResourceRecordA
dc1-adc3    DnsServerResourceRecordA

Comment: (If you edit what you tried and what happened into your question, it will help others see what your current state is, and will bump your question up to the top of the questions list to draw more attention to it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The A records are CIM objects, and the default output formatting provided with the DnsServer module must know how to format them, but converting them to string just gets you the DnsServerResourceRecordA text.

You need to get the `.RecordData.IPv4Address` property out, with a calculated property, e.g.

```
$arecords| Select-Object -Property hostname, @{name='IP'; Expression={ $_.RecordData.IPv4Address }}
```

aka

```
$arecords| select hostname, @{n='IP';E={$_.RecordData.IPv4Address}}
```

Comment: Thank you @TessellatingHeckler !!! That did it. I will try to better understand CIM objects.

Comment: @NomNomNom If this answer solves your problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you sir! I'm reading the initial instructions for my first badge now.